# in sequelize is it possible to paginate the Nested request using Nested eager loading?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using the [Nested eager loading](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models-usage/index.html#nested-eager-loading) funcionality, this is the sequelize example:

```
User.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Tool,
    as: 'Instruments',
    include: [{
      model: Teacher,
      where: {
        school: "Woodstock Music School"
      },
      required: false
    }]
  }]
}).then(function(users) {
  /* ... */
})
```

Imagine you want to do an `endpoint` 'summary' and you want to include the `Teacher model`, but only the first three results

It is possible using only the Nested eager loading?

Sequelize provides a way to achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying many things, I came to the conclusion that it can not do directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use limit and offset with teacher model

```
 User.findAll({
    include: [{
            model: Tool,
            as: 'Instruments',
            include: [{
                    model: Teacher,
                    where: {
                        school: "Woodstock Music School"
                    },
                      limit: 3,
                    required: false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}).then(function (users) {
    /* ... */
})
```